# Rerunning an if/else statement?

Tags: bash

I am writing a script that will check 2 values from a file. Both values have to pass in order to continue on in the script but I am having trouble with the whole checking process

```
#Run Checks 
savedStateTestHot{
#Call HotPatch GoldSavedState.properties;
if[StateDate == SpecficDate];then
    echo "StateDate Matches"
else
    echo "StateDate Does Not Match Cancel"
    #Rerun after 180 seconds to match the polling trigger 
    Rerun();

fi

if[StateStatus == SpecficStatus];then
    echo "StateStatus Matches"
else 
    echo "StateStatus Does Not Match Cancel"
    #Rerun after 180 seconds to match the polling trigger 
    Rerun();
fi
}
```

I want to modify it so that if the conditions dont match it reruns again and I need help with the final output, so if both conditions pass that test outputs "All conditions passed"

Comment: better start posting this code in http://www.shellcheck.net . It contains many basic errors that need cleaning  before going to the real point.

Comment: put it all into a loop: `while true [ do your stuff ]`, then break out of the loop when the conditions are met.

Comment: @fedorqui I am not worryed with the basic errors I am just looking for help with the logic, I can fix the basic errors after I know the logic

Comment: @MarcB could you show me and example of while loop ? if u got the time

Comment: @ClarkPamler93 that assumes that those with expert shell knowledge are better than the shell itself at interpreting your intent from code with basic errors in it. To be frank, that's a very faulty assumption.

Comment: Code with minor errors does not constitute a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), making your question off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Spaces are crucial in bash

The format of if statement is:

```
if [ something == something ] ...
```

or

```
if [[ something == something ]] ...
```

And if `StateDate` and such are variables, you need to use `"$StateDate"`.

> The format for a bash function is `funcname(){}` not `funcname{}`

You can use a `while` loop to return to the initial point if conditions aren't met.
Example:

```
while true;do
read p
if [ "$p" == "y" ];then
break
fi
done
```

In the above example, if you enter `y`, it will meet the condition and break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In shell, you can use while loop like so :

```
while [ condition ]
do
    command1
    command2
    commandN
done
```

So if you change the condition for both of your ifcase, you'll be set to do what you're asking, checking conditions before allowing your script to continue.